# Jdbc-odbc bridge with ms access don't understand greek characters?

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, jdbc, odbc

I hava a java appl , i can make connection between my ms access database and my appl but when i write greek character in a textfield then my database appears disunderstandings characters. If there is no solution how i could change my database and my source code?

---

So how i could change my source code to change the database? Which database i must to use (java embedded , mysql ) i don't know. I just want to accepet the greek characters and to be ease to make the correction on my source code!

This is one of the parts in my source code that i use the database.....

```
String dbuser = "";
String dbpasswd = "";
String DriverPrefix = "jdbc:odbc:";
Sting DataSource = "mydatabase";
....
....
....
....
String User = usernameLoginTxtField.getText();
String Password = pwLoginField.getText();
String SQLString = "select * from Administrators where username = '"+User+"' and password = '"+Password+"'";
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(DriverPrefix+DataSource, dbuser, dbpasswd);
stmt = con.createStatement();
rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Administrators where username = '"+User+"' and password = '"+Password+"'";
```

Please Help me... i would like to explain me exactly how i must to make th correction in the source code, how to convert the ms access database etc.....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Unfortunately the JDBC-ODBC driver has a bug http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6345277.

Comment: I found the solution, i just add the charSet with the encoding windows-1253 and i use the jdk version 7 so it works!