# Danish characters not displayed when selecting from Access through JDBC-ODBC Driver

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, character-encoding, jdbc-odbc

I have a .mdb Access Database which I have previously updated through a vbs script, which required some .csv files to be dumped from a site into a specified directory.

I realised that the site i loaded the csv files also had a webservice, so I decided to load through that instead. while testing, I wondered why the data in the tables wasn't being received properly. so I wrote a little test script:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ConventusImport {



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int jdkType = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
        if (jdkType != 32) {
            System.err.println("Running " + jdkType + " bit JDK - this may cause ODBC Issues. please run with 32-bit JDK");
        }
        try {
            //SQL connection
            String mdbFileName = "F:/TestDatabase.accdb";
            String dbConnectString = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + mdbFileName;

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("charSet", "windows-1252");//virker ved inserts, men ikke ved selects
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectString, props);
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM testTabel where id = 12"; // Ægår Ødisøn Ådisbærg
            stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            rs.next();
            byte[] rawBytes = rs.getBytes(2);

            String updateQuery = "insert into testTabel values(14, 'æøå ÆØÅ é€èéÈ')";
            stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery);

            //run through all charsets available, and try to decode byte array
            SortedMap availableCharsetsMap = Charset.availableCharsets();
            Set keySet = availableCharsetsMap.keySet();
            Iterator it = keySet.iterator();
            if (rawBytes != null && rawBytes.length != 0) {
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Charset chset = (Charset) availableCharsetsMap.get((String) it.next());
                    String stringLine = new String(rawBytes, chset);
                    System.out.println(stringLine + "\t\t" + chset.name());
                }
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConventusImport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConventusImport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I tried several charsets, and cp1252 works when I'm inserting, but when I'm selecting from the access database, I get `?`'s instead of the characters I expect.

For example, `Åse Sørensen` becomes `?se S?rensen`

the only other stackexchange post I can see are relevant don't solve my problem [Jdbc-odbc bridge with ms access don't understand greek characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998855/jdbc-odbc-bridge-with-ms-access-dont-understand-greek-characters) 
[How to correctly return special Spanish characters from a MS Access db with jdbc-odbc driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660569/how-to-correctly-return-special-spanish-characters-from-a-ms-access-db-with-jdbc)

EDIT:

I have tried UCANACCESS and it solves a lot of problems with ODBC and machine architecture..

unfortunately i cannot delete the question now.

Comment: Do u get Danish chars stored properly in DB?

Comment: Yes - characters are stored correctly, when i use cp1252 for inserts.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Danish chars stored properly in your DB then you need change your console settings to display them properly. Default encoding of console is not generally UTF-8 and hence when you try to print one, it is shown as question mark(`?`).

You can change your console setting in eclipse by going to:

```
Run Configuration > Common > Encoding > Select UTF8 from drop down.
```

Comment: thanks for the tip on the console settings, but I use netbeans, so that would be different settings...